# Effect of shaking the browser screen by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-effects

How do I make the effect of shaking the browser screen by javascript?

On googling, I found codes involving `window.moveBy(x,y)` which don't seem to work. I tried them.

**Any library or piece of code which would help me implement this kind of effect/animation?**

Comment: set the document body positioning to `relative/absolute` and modify `left/top/right/bottom` I guess

Comment: See this previous StackOverflow question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099141/javascript-browser-shake-on-firefox/5099453

Comment: @RandomHuman: the above example uses moveBy() which does not seem to work on my browser (maybe as Mathletics said, it is disabled in modern browsers)

Comment: moveBy is disabled, though of course many users don't hAve a

Answer (score 4):

You likely won't be able to move the actual browser window as that functionality is blocked in modern browsers. However, you can "shake" the contents of the window by animating the `body` left/right/up/down relative to the window.